# WebView blocking pop up windows?

Tags: android, html, android-webview, popupwindow

I'm using `WebView` to browse pesopay.com and it works properly, except when I pressed the submit button. Using internet browsers like Google Chrome will show a pop up window, it confirms the information you filled. But in my Android `WebView` nothing happened when I pressed the submit button. I think because `WebView` is not enabled to display a pop up window.

Can anyone point me what is wrong?

Here is my activity:

```
public class PaymentActivity extends Activity {

String amount1;     
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.payment);

         Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
            if(extras !=null)
            {
                amount1 = extras.getString("amount1");

            }

        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("javascript:window.onload = function(){setValue(\""+ amount1 +"\");};");
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");   
    }    
}
```

My web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function setValue(amount1) {
        myValue = amount1;
        document.getElementById("amount").value = myValue;

    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function rand ( n )
    {
        document.getElementById("orderRefId").value =  ( Math.floor ( Math.random ( ) * n + 1 ) );
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="rand(200000)">
        <!-- 
            Note: https://www.pesopay.com/b2c2/eng/payment/payForm.jsp for live payment URL
                  https://test.pesopay.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp for test payment URL
        -->
        <form method="POST" name="frmPayment" action="https://test.pesopay.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Order Reference No. (your reference number for every transaction that has transpired):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="orderRefId" name="orderRef" value="Test-001"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Amount:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value=""/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Currency Code - "608" for Philippine Peso, "840" for US Dollar:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="currCode" value="608"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Language:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lang" value="E"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Merchant ID (the merchant identification number that was issued to you - merchant IDs between test account and live account are not the same):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="merchantId" value="18056869"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon failed transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="failUrl" value="http://www.yahoo.com?flag=failed"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon successful transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="successUrl" value="http://www.google.com?flag=success"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon canceled transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cancelUrl" value="http://www.altavista.com?flag=cancel"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type of payment (normal sales or authorized i.e. hold payment):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="payType" value="N"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Payment Method - Change to "ALL" for all the activated payment methods in the account, Change to "BancNet" for BancNet debit card payments only, Change to "GCASH" for GCash mobile payments only, Change to "CC" for credit card payments only:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="payMethod" value="ALL"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Remark:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="remark" value="Asiapay Test"/></td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>    
            <td>Redirect:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="redirect" value="1"/></td>
        </tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>   

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </tbody>
        </table>    

        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i am getting right , you need to use **JavaScriptInterface**  for calling JavaScript function from Android.

Check this link which may help you :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392603/Android-addJavaScriptInterface

Or check some websettings :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportMultipleWindows%28boolean

try to put this code in onCreate()

```
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: But its just displaying a toast in webview.

Comment: the pop up that doesn't display in my web view is not what I created. it a pop up of the site that I'm browsing. link https://test.pesopay.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm2.jsp

Comment: ok ok i got it ,hav u tried this on onCreate() webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

Comment: or check some other we setting which may help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically%28boolean%29

Comment: +1. Thanks. `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);` is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The function which is responsible for dialogs in Webview is **[onJsAlert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onJsAlert(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.JsResult))** of WebChromeClient.

Here is sample code

```
  public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult jsResult) {
        // you can create your own dialog here or just return true for no pop up. 
        return true;
    }
}
```

and add this to your webview:

```
MyWebChromeClient myWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
webView.setWebChromeClient(myWebChromeClient);
```