# WebView not registering onclick javascript links

Tags: android, android-webview

I have the following class.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private WebView w;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    w = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    w.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    w.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    w.setClickable(true);
    w.loadUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert");
  }
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if(w.canGoBack())w.goBack();
    else super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

If you try clicking on the Try it alert box nothing fires.

How do I fix the WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the default `WebChromeClient` :

```
w.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Answer (score 0):

The webview does not show an `AlertDialog` automatically. You have to use `setWebChromeClient` to set a `WebChromeClient` and then override `onJsAlert` to show an `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question asked here [WebView blocking pop up windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823146/webview-blocking-pop-up-windows)
Try adding these:

```
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```