# Android WebView and site that needs to get local files

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I struggled with how to name this one, but basically I have a `WebView` that allows users to statically specify a URL and then display the page in side our app in a `WebView`. All fine and dandy - it works. However one user has specified `www.streamable.com` which allows a user to upload a video, and then provides a URL to that video.

The `WebView` loads the `www.streamable.com` site just fine, but does not seem to do anything when they hit the "Upload a video file" button. In a normal browser the following is displayed (even on a mobile device):

[image]

and the normal popup (after you choose which mechanism):

[image]

I visited the following `StackOverflow` examples, but they haven't worked:

[WebView blocking pop up windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823146/webview-blocking-pop-up-windows)

[How to display javascript popup in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354551/how-to-display-javascript-popup-in-android-webview)

[How to work with pop ups window in android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169821/how-to-work-with-pop-ups-window-in-android-webview)

Is this some Javascript restriction (tried those options), or a known security restriction that the `WebView` enforces that I haven't stumbled across?

Here is the code that I am using:

```
            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            }); 
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return true;
             }
            }); 
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("www.streamable.com");
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This do not answer directly your question but could help. Sometime ago I was having a similar issue with one specific web page (That page was not under my control), It was working on web, even with mobile browser but not with WebView, I tried different ways to make it work and I could not make it, for me one of the reason was because of the permissions to open the camera (you can check if you are using android Lollipop or more recent). But at the end the best solution that I found, and what I use instead of webview is

> Chrome Custom Tabs

You can check the the implementation here [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)
.

As they mention :

> The WebView is good solution if you are hosting your own content
>   inside your app. If your app directs people to URLs outside your
>   domain, we recommend that you use Chrome Custom Tabs

You can check all the detailed reasons in the link provided before.

Since you are accessing 3rd party web pages I think this is the way to go, and for sure the `www.streamable.com` site will work.

Comment: @alan1fm Thanks. I will research and give it a try.